# Specify the column to use when joining

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have some tables to specify standard email messages and the addresses from which they should be sent:

```
Email.Message
-------------
MessageId
Name
FromAddressId

Email.Address
-------------
AddressId
```

These tables are modeled in code using these classes:

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}

public class EmailMessage
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FromAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmailAddress FromAddress { get; set; }
}

var message = Db.EmailMessages
                .Where(m => m.Name == name)
                .Include(m => m.FromAddress)
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

I am using Fluent API to specify the relationship:

```
internal class EmailMessageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EmailMessage>
{
    public EmailMessageMap()
    {
        ToTable("Message", "Email");
        HasKey(p => p.MessageId);
        // What do I put here?
    }
}
```

How do I set up the join to use the `FromAddressId` of my `EmailMessage` class?  I've tried these options:

```
HasRequired(p => p.FromAddress).WithRequiredPrincipal(); // uses LEFT OUTER JOIN
HasRequired(p => p.FromAddress).WithRequiredDependent(); // uses INNER JOIN
```

These cause the SQL that gets created to use either a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or an `INNER JOIN`, but they always try to join `Message.MessageId` to `Address.AddressId`, which is incorrect.  How do I make it use the correct column (`FromAddressId`)?  I need to have something to replace the `// What do I put here?`, because otherwise I get the following exception:

> Invalid column name 'FromAddress_AddressId'

**EDIT:**  I can place a `[ForeignKey("FromAddressId")]` on top of the `FromAddress` property and it works:

```
[Extent1].[FromAddressId] = [Extent2].[AddressId]
```

Progress!  Now, how do I do this in Fluent API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, how do I do this in Fluent API?

```
HasRequired(p => p.FromAddress)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(p => p.FromAddressId);
```